# limit and probability measure in P(X=a)

Tags: limits, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Given a random variable $X$ with DF $F$ on some probability space, I wish to establish that $P(X=a)=\lim_{t\to a^-}P(t<X\le a)=\lim_{t\to a^-} (F(a)-F(t))=F(a)-F(a-)$. What I am unable to justify rigorously is the first equality here. Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: First inequality?  I don't see any.

Comment: Use the fact that if $A_n \searrow A$, then $P(A_n) \searrow P(A)$.

Comment: Sorry. Typo corrected.

Comment: @Mason Is $A_n=\{a-1/n<X\le a\}$ here?

Comment: @Shahab That will work.